# escape in a select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, select

In the following sql, what the use of escape is ?

```
select * from dual where dummy like 'funny&_' escape '&';
```

SQL*Plus ask for the value of _ whether escape is specified or not.

Comment: I think the documentation explains this pretty well: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm.

Comment: Please provide sample data which you are trying get.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of the escape clause is to stop the wildcard characters (eg. `%` or `_`) from being considered as wildcards, as per [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions007.htm)

The reason why you're being prompted for the value of `_` is because you're using `&`, which is also usually the character used to prompt for a substitution variable.

To stop the latter from happening, you could:

- change to a different escape character
- prior to running your statement, run `set define off` if you're using SQL*Plus (or as a script in a GUI, eg. Toad) or turn off the substitution variable prompting if you're using a GUI.
- change the define character to something different by running `set define <character>`

Answer (score 2):

The escape character is used to indicate that the underscore should be matched as an actual character, rather than as a single-character wildcard. [This is explained in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/conditions007.htm#SQLRF52141).

[image: like condition]

> You can include the actual characters % or _ in the pattern by using the ESCAPE clause, which identifies the escape character. If the escape character precedes the character % or _ in the pattern, then Oracle interprets this character literally in the pattern rather than as a special pattern-matching character.

If you didn't have the escape clause then the underscore would match any single character, so `where dummy like 'funny_'` would match `'funnyA'`, `'funnyB'`, etc. and not just an actual underscore.

The escape character you've chosen is `&` which is the default SQL*Plus client [substitution variable](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#CACIFHGB) marker. It has nothing to do with the `escape` clause, and using that is causing the `&_` part of the pattern to be interpreted as a substitution variable called `_`, hence your being prompted. As it isn't related, the `escape` clause has no effect on that.

The simplest thing is probably to choose a different escape character. If you want to use that specific escape character and not be prompted, [disable or change the substitution character](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG073):

```
set define off
select * from dual where dummy like 'funny&_' escape '&';
set define on
```

That will then match rows where dummy contains exactly the string `'funny_'`. (It's therefore equivalent to `where dummy = 'funny_'`, as there are no unescaped wildcards, making the `like` pattern matching redundant). It will not match any that *start* with that pattern (it's sort of like using `regexp_like` with start and end anchors, and you might be expecting it to work as if you hadn't supplied anchors, but it doesn't). You would need to add a % wildcard for that:

```
set define off
select * from dual where dummy like 'funny&_%' escape '&';
set define on
```

And if you want to match any that don't start with `funny_` but have it somewhere in the middle of the value, you would need to add another wildcard before it too:

```
set define off
select * from dual where dummy like '%funny&_%' escape '&';
set define on
```

You haven't shown any sample data or expected results to it isn't clear which pattern you need.

SQL Fiddle doesn't have substitution variables but [here's an example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7796bc/2) showing how those three patterns match various values.

Comment: Is there an example where there is a row from select instead of "no rows selected" ? I tried some and just got that.

Comment: @user2018791 - that depends on your data. Maybe you want a % wildcard before `funny` too, if that appears in the middle of a value? But you will never match if you're really querying against `dual`, as that has a single row with `dummy` value of `X`.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for the SQL LIKE Condition is:

```
expression LIKE pattern [ ESCAPE 'escape_character' ]
```

Parameters or Arguments

- `expression` : A character expression such as a column or field.
- `pattern` : A character expression that contains pattern matching. The patterns that you can choose from are:

  ```
   Wildcard | Explanation
   ---------+-------------
      %     | Allows you to match any string of any length (including zero length)
      _     | Allows you to match on a single character
  ```
- `escape_character`:  Optional. It allows you to test for literal instances of a wildcard character such as % or _.

Source : http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php